# Should I deactivate automatic migration in UA if I have created the GA4 property and tags in GTM?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

for our UA property I have created a GA4 property. The GA4 property is connected in GTM.
In GTM I have created the tags for GA4 like they are for UA with some adjustments if neccessary.

In the documentation it is said that the migration to GA4 will be done automatically on 1st July. Will my preparation be overriden if I do not deactivate the automatic migration in UA? Or can I let it activated and the automatic migration will look if it find something more that have to be adjusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The automatic transition to GA4 will create a new GA4 property for you, it won't do anything else in your GTM configs etc. Nothing will be overridden as well. You can keep your current GA4 setup.

You can opt-out of this automatic migration from your property settings. Please follow the Google official guide here: [Official Docs](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12938611?hl=en#optout&zippy=%2Cin-this-article)

Comment: Thank you. i have also opt-out the automatic migration.